# joining two tables with non-Primary key attributes using hibernate annotations

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have Table A with attributes A1(PK), A2, A3

I have another table B with attributes B1(PK), B2 and B3

now, I need to join table A and B on the basis of A3 = B3.

Can you tell me how to do it in hibernate annotations using join. 
The problem is that how to specify which column of Table A to be mapped on which Column of Table B in the mapping file where both column are not primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
B {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b3", referencedColumnName = "a3")
    privte A a;

}
```

You have to specify in the relationship columns by which they are joined.

For vise versa:

```
A {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "a3", referencedColumnName = "b3")
    privte List<B> bList;

}
```